# Uneven two column layout for fluid hybrid email

Tags: css, email, html-email, email-client

I'm working on an email for the client using the fluid hybrid method. I am trying to create a footer that is a two-column layout, but with uneven columns. I am looking for the left column (which contains an image) to be 58% of the email width (the max width of the email is 600px), and the right column (which contains text only) to be the remaining 42% width.

While testing through Litmus, Im able to get it to display without issue on most of the email clients. Outlook 2007, 2010 and Windows 10 Mail are giving me issues. Any ideas?

Here is a link to my [litmus build](https://litmus.com/builder/9ff0224).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you maybe include some code, and not just a reference to your project?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent far too long trying to get Outlook to respect column widths, I'd try the following:

The **very first row** of the troublesome table having only an `&nbsp;` in each cell but explicitly set the widths.

eg:

`<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="58%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="42%">&nbsp;</td>
    <\tr>
...`

This stops Outlook trying to be clever and resizing the columns to how it thinks they should be. It behaves as if it bases the widths on the first row of the table, so having explicit widths set with no content often does the trick.

Failing that, and it's a dirty trick - having an invisible 1px by 1px gif embedded is useful - as you can include it in each top row cell and set the width of that. Which is something even Outlook can't ignore.

`<img src="1px.gif" height="1" width="58%" />`